# Multiple HTTP thread pools (configuration) in a Glassfish instance under same virtual server

Tags: performance, glassfish-3, grizzly

I have created a new dedicated HTTP thread pool in my Glassfish v3 instance. Of course along with the thread pool, I have created a associated network listener with a dedicated port. However, the newly created thread pool and network listener sits in the same VIRTUAL server as that of the existing HTTP thread pool. Essentially this means that a single virtual server will have two network listeners and two thread pools.

The reason for this design is that I want the newly created thread pool to cater to longer HTTP requests (like a 50MB download file). The other HTTP thread pool will cater to relatively smaller requests like a web-page download, diag reports stats etc.The newly created thread pool makes sense because the client requests tie up the HTTP worker thread resource. So longer the time it takes the client to download the files (50MB), the longer the HTTP resouces are tied there by making rejecting other HTTP requests. I don't expose the port externally. Apache proxy pass takes care of routing my requests to appropriate ports.

I wanted to understand if there is any flaw/drawback with this approach.
Glassfish version that I use is 3.1.1 or v3

**EDIT**

Adding my comments from the responses below to add more clarity to the question

However, my question is to understand if there are any issues creating multiple thread pools under one virtual server. We usually create one thread pool per domain (or virtual server). By creating two thread pools (and listeners) in a single domain am I violating anything or this is considered a normal practice?

The only caveat I found with this approach is. Say I have two port 8080 and 8085 assigned to network listeners. All the requests that are accessible on 8080 and also accessible through port 8085. Is this expected? But that is more from testing perspective since I don't expose my port externally anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach makes sense.

As alternative, you can use Servlet 3.0 async request processing capabilities and make a decision if you want to delegate the long/heavy requests to a separate thread directly in Glassfish, rather than using Apache for it.

Comment: Well Apache is just for proxing requests (Proxy Pass). It understand the request and directs it to appropriate port. That essentially means all my HTTP traffic comes on port 80 (Apache) and it further bifurcated from there.

Comment: Regarding, async request processing. I tried that part. It seems to take more memory as I would expect for NIO processing. Unfortunately, I am not at liberty memory wise (both heap and native). Sync processing made sense and I have the liberty to throttle client requests. I can control when the client can fire HTTP requests. Therefore this approach.

Comment: The only caveat I found with this approach is. Say I have two port 8080 and 8085 assigned to network listeners. All the requests that are accessible on 8080 and also accessible through port 8085. Is this expected? But that is more from testing perspective since I don't   expose my port externally anyways.

Comment: As long as they assigned to the same virtual server - yes, it's expected. It's a same situation, when you have Glassfish out-of-the-box and two ports 8080 and 8181 expose same applications (8080 via HTTP, 8181 via HTTPS)

Comment: Yeah kind of same scenario, but both 8080 and 8181 use the same thread-pool. My use case is slightly different. I have the a new threadpool associated with a network listener.

Comment: 8080 and 8181 (out-of-the-box) share the same thread pool configuration, but the actual instances are different.

Answer (score 0):

### Consider scenarios below:

**Assumption:** You are not having any logic to determine the size of incoming HTTP request and route to a specific threadpool.

1. ThreadpoolA which serves html pages and light-weight requests has HTTP requests to be served and let us say due to thread synchronization issues is having some latency. During this situation, considering ThreadpoolA is full, requests get routed to threadpoolB which might have some capacity but may take way too long to complete its large size HTTP request. This leads to blocked threads irrespective of their urgency to be served.
2. Let us say you are using round-robin approach to route incoming HTTP request to a specific threadpool. If you have two or few incoming HTTP requests of large size at one point of time, your both thread pools are busy serving large requests and blocking/delaying light-weight http requests to be served.

**Assumption:** You have a logic to determine size of HTTP requests and route to a specific threadpool. This would need you to capture some stats on how well your thread pools are occupied now and make best use of them by routing http requests based on amount of work left for each threadpool. If not, you might have a dedicated threadpool which handles large http requests only but be there idle with no utilization until a large http request of certain size arrives. Also, let us say you have set a size of >=10MB to be routed to ThreadpoolB and <10MB to ThreadpoolA, the problem is worse if you have unexpected few requests with size let us say 9MB which is substantially large and still keeps hitting ThreadpoolA while ThreadpoolB is free and blocking your HTTP requests which are of less size. So, an ideal size to determine when to route your HTTP request is also a key determinant factor for optimal performance which purely depends on workload characteristics of your application.

Comment: @Chatanya Appreciate your response. However, my question is to understand if there are any issues creating multiple thread pools under one virtual server. We usually create one thread pool per domain (or virtual server). By creating two thread pools (and listeners) in a single domain am I violating anything or this is considered a normal practice?

Comment: and as I said before Apache will route my requests to appropriate thread pools. So, I have full control over which request to route to which thread pool.